# Sqlite: Custom join two tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm kind of stuck with this problem: I have a sqlite database containing two tables connected using a common id. I want to retrieve data from both the tables, and populate a new table say 'table3' having columns 'category_id', 'question', correct_answer', 'wrong_answer1', wrong_answer2', 'wrong_answer3'. How can this be accomplished? Please see the picture below.

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: This looks like a simple join on question ID.  Based on that you can use an INSERT to create your table.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can make use of join

Comment: Can you please provide me the exact query, I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: What database are you using? (oracle, sql server, mysql, etc.)

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff: You can see the sample data in the picture I have uploaded.

Comment: @Brian DeMilia: sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always have one right answer and three wrong answers you can use this query:

```
       SELECT Q.category_id, 
              Q.value AS Question,
              RA.value AS CorrectAns,
              WA1.value AS WrongAns1,
              WA2.value AS WrongAns2,
              WA3.value AS WrongAns3
         FROM question Q
   INNER JOIN answer RA  ON (RA.question_id = Q.id  AND RA.isCorrect = 1)
   INNER JOIN answer WA1 ON (WA1.question_id = Q.id AND WA1.isCorrect = 0)
   INNER JOIN answer WA2 ON (WA2.question_id = Q.id AND WA2.isCorrect = 0)
   INNER JOIN answer WA3 ON (WA3.question_id = Q.id AND WA3.isCorrect = 0)
        WHERE WA1.id < WA2.`id`
          AND WA2.id < WA3.`id`
          AND Q.id = 102752
```

If the number of wrong answer is not always three you can use this other query.

```
       SELECT Q.category_id, 
              Q.value AS Question,
              RA.value AS CorrectAns,
              GROUP_CONCAT(WA.value) AS WrongAnswers
         FROM question Q
   INNER JOIN answer RA ON (RA.question_id = Q.id AND RA.isCorrect = 1)
    LEFT JOIN answer WA ON (WA.question_id = Q.id AND WA.isCorrect = 0)
        WHERE Q.id = 102752
```

Note that in this case all the wrong answers are returned in the same column.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jordi. Your query ran flawlessly.